# PhpStorm - watchify connection bug

Tags: phpstorm, watchify

When I switched my editor to PhpStorm I found a bug working with watchify. By default watchify makes browserify to update a bundle if one of files using in a bundle is changed. Generally it works. But sometimes on a file nothing happens. On the next change a bundle is updated. And later this bug could happens againg - nothing is changed on a file change.

In Sublime Text, my previous editor, there was not this but. Everything worked as expected. And even now when I make changes in files a bundle was updated. So the issue is in how PhpStorm saves file.

I tried to check this with `gulp-watch`. I run watch on files and log a message on files change. In this case a message is logged on every change. I am not sure how watchify works. I considered watch changes with `gulp-watch` but I can not find how to delegate changes to watchify. So for now I must track if a bundle is updated and if it does not I have to make a unnecessary change (add and remove a space) for watchify to run it.

Should I update PhpStorm? Or you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be an issue with hanndling safe writes... Please try turning '**Safe write**' option ( **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Use "safe write" (save changes to temporary file first)**) off - does it make any difference?

Comment: Perfect. Did not expect this issue could be resolved.